# React - Passing variable to path in redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a code that redirects to a default path if a certain flag is set. The redirected URL contains a variable id. I tried

`return <Redirect to = {'/products/:id/details'}/>`

and

`return <Redirect to = {'/products/${id}/details'}/>`

but neither of them will insert the id to the URL.

This is my code:

```
if (flag)
    return <Redirect to = {'/products/:id/details'}/>

return(
    //renders something
)
```

Comment: either use tempate literals (shown below) or concat string `{'/products/'+id+'/details'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update like this with `Template_literals`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals?retiredLocale=vi

```
 return <Redirect to = {`/products/${id}/details`}/>
```